# getting type error when I try to assign interface to a property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using typescript in my Angular project
trying to assign IInfoPage interface to data

```
    export interface IInfoPage {
      href: string;
      icon: string;
      routing: boolean;
      order: number;
      styleType: string;
    }

    public pageData: IInfoPage;


    this.configService.PageData.subscribe((res) => {
        this.pageData = res.SubMenu.find(data => location.pathname.includes('path'));
    })
```

But as I see this.pageData alerts and gives me this error:

```
Type 'ISubMenuType | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IInfoPageSubData'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IInfoPageSubData'.
```

So How can I solve this issue?

Comment: what is the data type of your response ??

Comment: If its the same as IInfoPage you can just cast you response as IInfoPage

Comment: `find` can return undefined,  so if `ISubMenuType` & `IInfoPageSubData` are duck type compatible, then you need to do a find check first..  eg.. `const f = res.SubMenu.find(...); if (f) { this.pageData = f }`

Comment: `find` can fail to find anything, and will return `undefined`, you can make your `pageData` optional, or only assign to it if `find` actually found something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.find()` can always return `undefined`, so you'll need to check whether or not `find` has returned a result.

```
const result = res.SubMenu.find(data => location.pathname.includes('path'));

if(result)
  this.pageData = result;
```